# Trouble when throwing a custom error from a claim based (WIF) WCF service - The nonce is invalid or replayed

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wif

Scenario: IIS 7.5, MVC 4 claim based client and WCF Claim based (WIF) service .net framework 4.5. I'm trying to throw a custom error from the WCF service and catch it on the client side.

Custom Fault on service side is:

```cs
[DataContractAttribute]
public class AppModelFault
{

    private string message;

    public AppModelFault(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message
    {
        get { return this.message; }
        set { this.message = value; }
    }
}
```

I have this inside the interface definition for the service method

```cs
[OperationContract]
[FaultContractAttribute(typeof(AppModelFault))]
Int64 SaveApplication(Application app);
```

And this is how I am throwing the error on the service side:

```cs
var errorMsg = "Custom error message";
throw new FaultException<AppModelFault>(new AppModelFault(errorMsg), new FaultReason(errorMsg));
```

On the client I'm catching the custom error like this:

```cs
catch (FaultException<AppModelFault> fault)
{
    return Json(new JsonMessage(Response, false, fault.Detail.Message, JsonMessageType.Error));
}
```

This works fine when testing this locally, then the AppModelFault exception is flowing without problems to the client. However when I publish this to the dev machine this does not work. When I add wcf trace logging I get the below error on the service side before the message is sent to the client.

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/is-IS/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Isb.ApplicationModel.Service-10-130300371813153037</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The nonce is invalid or replayed.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ProcessPrimarySignature(SignedXml signedXml, Boolean isFromDecryptedSource)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ProcessEncryptedData(EncryptedData encryptedData, TimeSpan timeout, Int32 position, Boolean eagerMode, Boolean&amp;amp; primarySignatureFound)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ProcessSecurityHeader(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, Message&amp;amp; message, SecurityToken requiredSigningToken, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message&amp;amp; message, String actor, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp;amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ServerSecurityChannel`1.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp;amp; message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.ProcessReceivedRequest(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.OnRead(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ReadAsyncResult.Complete(Int32 bytesRead, Int32 hresult, IntPtr pbAsyncReceiveBuffer, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.OnAsyncCompletion(Int32 bytesCompleted, Int32 hresult, IntPtr pAsyncCompletionContext)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.AsyncCompletionHandler(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, Int32 bytesCompleted, Int32 hresult, IntPtr pAsyncCompletionContext)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The nonce is invalid or replayed.</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

The client gets an "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message"

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Can you please show us your configuration?